# use flash action script to develop online games

Tags: flash, actionscript

For short: can you tell me some great resource to study if I want to develop online games using flash technology? Including 3D games.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can start with the newly released [Flash Platform Game Technology Center](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/games/) 
on Adobe Devnet.

There are quite a few books out there on as3 games, I'll try not to repeat the ones already mentioned:

[The Essential Guide to Flash Games:
Building Interactive Entertainment with ActionScript](http://friendsofed.com/book.html?isbn=9781430226147)
[image: Essential Guide to Flash Games cover]
<sub>(source: [friendsofed.com](http://friendsofed.com/img/cover/9781430226147.jpg))</sub>

This is a great book, tons of great examples, industry tips. This is pretty complete,
as it starts with the basics and ends with promoting and obtaining revenue from games
through systems such as MochiAds.

Another book that is filled with tips earned through experience is
[Real-world Flash Game Development: How to Follow Best Practices and Keep your Sanity](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/9780240811789)

[image: Real-world Flash Game Development cover]
<sub>(source: [safaribooksonline.com](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/static/201005-657-my/images/9780240811789/9780240811789_s.jpg))</sub>

[Foundation Game Design with Flash](http://www.friendsofed.com/book.html?isbn=9781430218210)

[image]
<sub>(source: [friendsofed.com](http://www.friendsofed.com/img/cover/9781430218210.jpg))</sub>

Nice and easy start for beginners.

[Flash Game University](http://flashgameu.com/)

[Flash Game University Cover|Size=200x260px http://66.79.179.141/screen/it-ebooks/que-actionscript-30-gameprogramming.jpg](http://66.79.179.141/screen/it-ebooks/que-actionscript-30-gameprogramming.jpg)

For Multiplayer I would recommend:

[ActionScript for Multiplayer Games and Virtual Worlds](http://jobemakar.blogspot.com/2009/06/actionscript-for-multiplayer-games-and.html)

[image]

For 3D I would recommend [Papervision Essentials](http://www.packtpub.com/papervision3d-essentials?utm_source=blog.papervision3d.org&utm_medium=spons&utm_content=pod&utm_campaign=mdb_000379)

[image]
<sub>(source: [paultondeur.com](http://www.paultondeur.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/papervision3d-essentials-small.jpg))</sub>

Recently an Away3D book has been released:
[The Essential Guide to 3D in Flash](http://friendsofed.com/book.html?isbn=9781430225416)
[image: The Essential Guide to 3D in Flash cover]
<sub>(source: [friendsofed.com](http://friendsofed.com/img/cover/9781430225416.jpg))</sub>

If you're really into 3D and the web, I would recommend having a look at
[Unity Game Development Essentials](http://www.packtpub.com/unity-game-development-essentials/mid/301109ugkci2?utm_source=richardleggett.co.uk&utm_medium=affiliate&utm_content=blog&utm_campaign=mdb_001661)

[image]
<sub>(source: [learnunity3d.com](http://learnunity3d.com/wp-content/uploads//2009/10/unityGameDevelopmentEssentials.jpg))</sub>

Not specifically games oriented, but very handy, are Keith Peter's books on animation:
[Foundation Actionscript 3.0 Animation:
Making Things Move!](http://www.friendsofed.com/book.html?isbn=9781590597910)
[image]
<sub>(source: [friendsofed.com](http://www.friendsofed.com/img/cover/1590597915.jpg))</sub>

and

[AdvancED ActionScript 3.0 Animation](http://www.friendsofed.com/book.html?isbn=9781430216087)
[image]
<sub>(source: [friendsofed.com](http://www.friendsofed.com/img/cover/9781430216087.jpg))</sub>

These would be the books. Of course there are lot of online learning resources out there.

More Adobe propaganda, the video presentations from **MAX 2009** are online now, you might want
to check out:

1. [Building Great Games With Flash](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/max-2009-design/building-great-games-with-flash/) (skip to 14:45, they didn't chop the video)
2. [Flash Player Gaming Showcase](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/max-2009-design/flash-platform-gaming-showcase/)
3. [MochiMedia Flash Gaming Summit 2010 Coverage](http://mochiland.com/articles/session-recordings-from-flash-gaming-summit)

Comment: @Skilldrick Thanks! I didn't know about that book. There were quite a few good books 'back in the day', like Flash MX 2004 Games Most Wanted. I guess the whole 'hacky' nature of as2 made it all a bit more 'creative' :)

Answer (score 3):

[GameDev.net](http://www.gamedev.net) is a good resource for learning game development. Have a look at [their review of Game Development With Actionscript](http://www.gamedev.net/columns/books/bookdetails.asp?productid=314). Try searching GameDev.net for ActionScript, you'll find a lot there.

Answer (score 0):

This resource is a bit outdated, because it is still utilizing adobe flash cs4. But it will be useful to just get started with flash game programming with AS3:

http://www.youtube.com/user/DevNote/videos.

Not mine, I am still a newbie too when this answer was posted.